# Application_Activation screen orientation Windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, popup, orientation

I have an application running in landscape mode. I therefore wanted a popup showing when Applcation_activation was fired, so Authentication and data updating could happen in the background. But the problem is the app is running in landscape mode.

So if my application is starting when the phone is held in portrait mode, the popup will be shown like this. I therefore wanted to make sure the orientation was correct, and if not make a rotation manually in the code.

But I cannot access this.SupportedOrientation, so how do you display a popup from the event Application_activated?

**A Solution**
A solution is of course to not use the event or simply set a flag and do the code in the navigatedTo event handlers for each page. But this is not a nive way to do it, when the event exists.

Anyy suggestion is appreciated

**Screen Shots from two of my apps**

**Portrait**

[image]

**Landscape**

[image]

**popup**

Basicly simple code.

```
Popup startup =new popup();
UsercontrolScreen childpopup =new UsercontrolScreen();
startup.child = childpopup;
startup.isOpen = true;
```

It is the same code for both, only the child is different.

Comment: You should not show a popup during the application events, instead use your page events like OnNavigatedTo within MainPage

Comment: Okay so I should use OnNavigatedTo on all my pages. Does not seem smart.

Comment: If your app only supports Landscape, I don't see what the issue is. Your xaml (or popup) will always show as landscape, regardless of phone orientation

Comment: not through the application_activated event. Of course if I make the popup appear in OnNavigatedTo events they are in landscape with no problem. But this would force me to make the code in every page, where if I could use the application_activated event I did not have to focus on this.

Comment: Have you heard of object inheritance? With no idea of your requirements, you can create a new MyPhoneApplicationPage that does this in it's OnNavigatedTo. All pages would inherit from it and they all benefit

Comment: Yeah okay, that could be a solution :) thanks.

Comment: But still if I have a portrait application I can do what I want but not in a Landscape application ?

Comment: What do you mean? Can you share more of what you are trying to do?

Comment: Added two screenshots from my apps

Comment: awesome, So it's the "Viking saying #5" you are having trouble with? Can you post the code you are using.

Comment: Yeps it is the problem. I am not using any fancy code. Creating a popup in the activation_application,  adding my usercontrol as a child and simply setting isopen property to true. As I also did in the portrait version.

Comment: Can you share (either here or a gist) a sample of the popup you are showing

Comment: @ShawnKendrot i added the code, nothing special.

Comment: Got it, this looks like a problem with adding the popup after orientation has taken place. Try rotating the child. `UsercontrolScreen childpopup = new UsercontrolScreen { RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(0.2,1), RenderTransform = new CompositeTransform { Rotation = 90}};` Play with the RenderTransformOrigin until it works, or adjust the Margin

Comment: @ShawnKendrot Yes that is a solution. But the problem is the render transform will only work in one direction, ie. Either right landscape or left landscape. So by using the transform I will on start up force the user to hold the phone in one way, not so nice for the user friendliness. And since I cannot access the orientation from the event. So that is why I do not see this as a solution for the problem.

Comment: Why can you not use `RootFrame.Orientation`. Also, if you put the popup in the page xaml, it works great w/o any transform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to add an overlay from within the App class, and always have it respect orientation, add it directly to the page content

```
private void Application_Activated(object sender, ActivatedEventArgs e)
{
    var activePage = (PhoneApplicationPage) RootFrame.Content;
    var pageContent = (Grid) activePage.Content;

    UsercontrolScreen childpopup = new UsercontrolScreen();

    Grid.SetRowSpan(childpopup , pageContent.RowDefinitions.Count);
    pageContent.Children.Add(childpopup );
}
```

Using this approach you would need to remove the content as well. Maybe have an X button on the control that would remove itself, or maybe fire a `Closed` event so the App could remove it from the grid. You would also need remove the control within the Deactivated event. Or, not add it again within the the Activated event if it was deactivated twice.

Comment: This looks awesome, Thanks. I will look into this later. But as my usercontrolScreen is not a popup. I think I would need to create the popup and add that to the pageContent. But looks awesome. I would ask you if you have time to look at another problem I have http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22283799/viewport-origin-animation/22478865?noredirect=1#comment34229911_22478865 I would give you a bounty for that, because I have not been able to solve that either.

Comment: Do not add the control to a popup, adding it the way above will cover the entire screen and center it. I forgot to mention to also set the ColumnSpan for the "childPopup" control (UsercontrolScreen)

Comment: ´The popup is shown as I wanted. Then I am at the problem of removing it. I decided to introduce a close button, that will be shown only in the cases where it is come from Application_Activated event. I then in the new click event wanted to do:

            var activePage = (PhoneApplicationPage)RootFrame.Content;
            var pageContent = (Grid)activePage.Content;

            pageContent.Children.Remove(this);
But RootFrame is not supported. Any Idea of how to accessing it without parsing it when creating the control?

Comment: Instead of RootFrame I tried 
            var activePage = ((PhoneApplicationFrame)Application.Current.RootVisual).Content; But have not been able to do it.

Comment: Are you trying to remove the control from within the Control code, or App code? The RootVisual of the current app is a PhoneApplicationFrame.

Comment: Did you try the following: activePage = (PhoneApplicationPage)((PhoneApplicationFrame) Application.Current.RootVisual).Content;