# Move object in ViewportControl WP8

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-8, drag-and-drop, viewport

I'm using the ViewportControl to scroll around and zoom in and out of my Map. In this map I've got a green ellipse which I wish to move around. Previously I used a ScrollViewer where I set the manipulationMode of the ScrollViewer to control, and thus making it capable of moving my ellipse around. However I can't find a similar way for the ViewportControl. So is there a way to move my ellipse around?

The code I've got so far is:

The xaml part where I have my ViewportControl around my map

```
   <ViewportControl x:Name="ViewPortTestTest" Bounds="0,0,1271,1381.5" Height="480" Width="800" Canvas.ZIndex="1" Grid.Row="1">
        <ViewportControl.RenderTransform>
            <CompositeTransform x:Name="myTransformTest"/>
        </ViewportControl.RenderTransform>

        <View:Map x:Name="ZoomableContent" >
            <View:Map.RenderTransform>
                <CompositeTransform x:Name="myTransform" />
                <!-- ScaleX="{Binding Map.imageScale}" ScaleY="{Binding Map.imageScale}"/>-->
            </View:Map.RenderTransform>
        </View:Map>
    </ViewportControl>
```

It is in the map where I add the ellipse. The viewModel where I manipulate my ellipse

```
public void ManStart(ManipulationStartedEventArgs e)
    {

        e.Handled = true;

        ViewportControl VP = FindParentOfType<ViewportControl>(ChampViewModelSel);


       }
    }

    public void ManDelta(ManipulationDeltaEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = true;


        Point fingerPosition = e.DeltaManipulation.Translation;

        Temp.x = fingerPosition.X;
        Temp.y = fingerPosition.Y;

        }
    }
```

Where Temp.x and Temp.y is the new position of the ellipse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you could try to use [TouchPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff434208.aspx) from XNA and `Touch.FrameReported` event for this purpose. Probably Map and VieportControl handle the manipulation event so it won't fire with your code.

In my proposal `Touch_FrameReported` will be fired every time you touch the screen, so we have to check only for situations we need - here comes `IsGestureAvailable` and `TouchAction`. Simple code can look like this:

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    TouchPanel.EnabledGestures = GestureType.FreeDrag;
    Touch.FrameReported += Touch_FrameReported;
}

private void Touch_FrameReported(object sender, TouchFrameEventArgs e)
{
    if (TouchPanel.IsGestureAvailable) // check only dragging 
    {
       // get point relative to Viewport
       TouchPoint mainTouch = e.GetPrimaryTouchPoint(ViewPortTestTest);
       // check if drag has completed (key up)
       if (mainTouch.Action == TouchAction.Up)
       {
          Temp.x = mainTouch.Position.X;
          Temp.y = mainTouch.Position.Y;
       }
    }
}
```

You can read more about Gestures [here at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff827740.aspx) and [on this blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nicgrave/archive/2010/07/12/touch-gestures-on-windows-phone-7.aspx).

You can also check other GestureTypes and for example check if `TouchAction.Down` and user clicked on your Ellipse.

These methods give you many possibilities to read `TouchPoints` and their `Actions` so maybe it will help.

---

It took me a while to find a way how to disable Vieport. I've found a little 'hack' for that, it will be easier if your VieportControl was only horizontal or vertical (there is a lock property, but doesn't work for both). Here is this little 'hack' which should disable both horizontal and vertical scrolling:

```
Rect originalBounds = new Rect();
private void Touch_FrameReported(object sender, TouchFrameEventArgs e)
{
    TouchPoint myTouchPoint = e.GetPrimaryTouchPoint(ViewPortTestTest);
   // disable scrolling
   if (myTouchPoint.Action == TouchAction.Down) // here probably some other statement like if user hit ellipse
   {
       originalBounds = ViewPortTestTest.Bounds;
       ViewPortTestTest.Bounds = ViewPortTestTest.Viewport; // set current view as Bounds
   }

    // more logic

   // enable once again
   if (myTouchPoint.Action == TouchAction.Up)
        ViewPortTestTest.Bounds = originalBounds;
}
```

When I want to disable scrolling - I set bounds of the VieportControl to the current view (and I remember original ones). When I want to enable scrolling - I bring back original bounds.

As I've tested it - it is working - of course it needs a little more logic in locking if statement, so that it won't lock every time you touch the screen.

Comment: Not sure if i'm understanding the right, but when I drag my finger won't the ViewportControl still scroll while I'm dragging my finger? or what part is it that makes sure the ViewportControl won't scroll?

Comment: @JonasN89 You are right that the first version won't prevent from scrolling. It took me some time to find a way how to achieve 'locked' viewport - it is not so easy as it seems. I've tried a little 'hack', which you can see in my edited answer.

Comment: I tried implementing your idea, but apparently it is not cropping the screen right. I tried looking at the bounds and it does not seem like it uses the top or left, any help?

Comment: Seems like it does not know how big the area in my viewportcontrol is. So when I use positive top and left coordinates they are not used but if I use negative they are used. My problem I think is that the viewportcontrol does not know it has an object 1000x1000 inside. I have tried setting the width and height but that eliminates scrolling but then I can manipulate the element. I also tried changing width and height in code so scrolling works, but then it does not set the correct view. Any idea for this maybe the dispatcher needs to be used ?

Comment: @JonasN89 Give me a little time - I'm at work now and I'll play with it this evening.

Comment: @JonasN89 I think I've found a solution - [take a look at this test](http://1drv.ms/1lPoeY5). I've put an image in ViewPort, you can scroll it and when you click the button above, scrolling is disabled, click again - enabled. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, it worked, I did not end up using the the rendertransform you added, but by adding the canvas around the zoomableContent, that helped and now it works. Any idea why I only has to add a Canvas to make it work?

Comment: @JonasN89 I thought that the problem may be that when parent control is changing (ViewPort) its child (Image) is trying to fit it - that is why it was probably cropped. I thought that with Canvas can be different as positioning does not take into account the size of the page. And I've ended with result you can see. I've also tried with setting the margin of the image but it hadn't worked.